# Twitter web page remains open after closing the app

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, android-browser

Twitter auth is working fine in my app.But when I tweet and close my app,the webpage of twitter is still open in browser.What is the problem? How to close this page(Browser).

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After successful login is your application getting started.
If no means callback url is not set properly and due to which this is happening.

Comment: The callback url at twitter can be any url u need to provide.But at the coding if your url is x-oauthflow-twitter" + "://" + "decentrale"; then at the manifest your code should be  <data
                    android:host="decentrale"
                    android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />