# Twitter webpage not closed after back to the application

Tags: android, webview, twitter4j

> I have integrate twitter application to my application.This is working fine for me but when i open the web page for twitter and then call back to my application at that time the twitter web page not closed thanks...and i am using this link but not understanding 
>   [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889582/twitter-web-page-remains-open-after-closing-the-app)

```
protected void Login() {
    ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder=new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITCONSUMER_KEY);
    configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTERSECRET_KEY);
    Configuration config=configBuilder.build();
    TwitterFactory twitterFactory=new TwitterFactory(config);
    twitter=twitterFactory.getInstance();
    try {
        requestToken=twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CallbackURL);
        Log.i(TAG,"RequestTocenisntance:"+requestToken);
        TwitterMainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: Top page]
[image: below web page]

Comment: @divoom12 i post my code

Comment: @divoom12 hai buddy send answer for my question